# edit image in jquery tinymce?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, tinymce

I am using jquery tinymce. I am editing an image inside tinymce using my below codes. Unfortunately it not works in ie7. How can i make it to work in ie7

```
file="good.img";
id=2;
alt="alternate";
class="aligncenter"
title="title_of_img";
width=150;
height=150;

tinymce.activeEditor.$("img[src$='"+file+"']").attr({'id' : faq_media_id , 'alt' : alternate , 'class' : align , 'title' : title , 'width' : width , 'height' : height});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will work in FF and IE8 (actually i do not have an IE7 available for testing)

```
ed = tinymce.get(editor_id);
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').css('display','block');
$(ed.getBody()).find('img').css('margin','0px auto');
```

Comment: i just installed IETester to be able to test under IE7 environment

Comment: the code above even works under IE7 - please tell me what you exactly call (you need to have the editor_id at hand and an image altready in the editor in order to make this work)